# Unity 3D game objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working with unity, I am trying to move my two game objects on touch in different directions. used movetowards method. but it did not work. do I missing any available classes/methods?

Comment: without code, we cannot find the missing !

Answer (score 0):

you should type

```
mygameobject.transform.translate(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,mygameobject.transform.position.z);
```